# Getting an error while pushing the code from local system to Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

Getting an error while Pushing a cypress code folder from local system to Gitlab using cmd prompt..

```
C:\Users\Dwaipayan\Documents\Git Push>git push -uf origin main
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/mainbuildrepo/cypressautomation.git/' not found
```

I tried to push it my personal Gitlab account.. but same error is coming...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, post the error as text in the question.

Comment: It says that the project either does not exist or you don’t have permission to access it.